# How to programatically show jquery qtip tooltips as error notifiers

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I need to programatically show qtip tooltips as error notifiers in a form I am working on. The form submits via ajax, and returns an object with an action, and if there are error an array of field names with error text to be show.

```
if (response.action == 'error') {
  // We would put tooltip on appropriate items here
  for (var key in response.text){
    //alert( "Key: " + key + " Value: " + response.text[key] );
    jQuery(key).qtip({
      content: {
        text: response.text[key],
        prerender: true
      },
      style: {
        theme: 'red',
        tip : {corner : "bottomLeft", size : { x : 12, y : 12 }}
      },
      position : {
        corner : {
          target : "topRight", 
          tooltip : "bottomLeft"
        }
      },
      show : {
        ready : true, // show when created on orderError call
        when : false // never show unless explicitly called
      }

    });
  jQuery(key).qtip("show");
  }
}
```

Above is the relevant chuck of code - stepping through it, it all seems to be fine, but I can't get the tooltips to fire up and show on the page. Has anyone had success doing this or is there anything obvious I am doing wrong?

Comment: I hope, i got the formatting right.

Comment: hi - key is the id of the field (aha! that might be it - it is missing the #) - response.text[key] is the error text.

Comment: okay so that was step one - getting the correct id. Now I need to just get the tips to show as soon as "show" is called - now they popup on mouseover.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out in the comments, one problem is that you need to make sure your `key` variable is a valid jQuery selector for the q-tip API call `jQuery(key).qtip("show");` to work.

Your other problem (mouseover pop-ups) might be related to your show options:

```
show : {
    ready : true, // show when created on orderError call
    when : false // never show unless explicitly called
}
```

`when: false` will mean q-tip will wait for your `.qtip("show");` call, so that should work OK.
But `ready : true` will make the q-tip show as soon as the DOM is ready, which then makes your API call to "show" redundant.

Try it with:

```
show : {
    when : false 
}
```

And see if thats any better.

You might also need:

```
hide: {
     when: false
}
```

... to prevent the tooltips from disappearing when you mouseout of the linked elements. (You might then also need some other way for the user to hide the tooltips)